# Hamburger menu come under the div when I open?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, navbar, hamburger-menu

I wanted to write web app that is capable in all device so I design nav bar for full screen and I wanted to design hamburger menu for small device but just my skill page has this problem. When I open the menu, menu will go under the div and rest of the link on menu can't be click. Here is my app link https://yasamanforouzesh.herokuapp.com/

```
     .nav-container {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 80px;
      }
      .Hnavbar {
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    
      .navbar-logo {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        justify-self: start;
        float: left;
        width: 65px;
        height: 75px;
      }
    
      .nav-menu {
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left: -100%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        text-align: center;
        justify-self: end;
        background-color: red;
        height: 57vh;
        z-index: 3;
      }
      .nav-links {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
      }
    
      .nav-menu.active {
        background-color: black;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
      }
    
      #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
      }
    
      .menu-toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        display: block;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: white;
      }          
<div className="nav-container">
                    <nav className="Hnavbar">
                        <img className="navbar-logo" src="/yasi1.jpg"/>
                        <div className={`menu-toggle ${isactive}`}id="mobile-menu" onClick={checkClass}>
                            <span className="bar"></span>
                            <span className="bar"></span>
                            <span className="bar"></span>
                        </div>
                        <ul className={`nav-menu ${active}`}>
                            <li className="list"><a href="/" className="nav-links">Home</a></li>
                            <li className="list"><a href="/about" className="nav-links">About</a></li>
                            <li className="list"><a href="/skills" className="nav-links">Skills</a></li>
                            <li className="list"><a href="/projects" className="nav-links">Projects</a></li>
                            <li className="list"><a href="/contact" className="nav-links">Contact</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
```

[image: Here is the picture]

Answer (score 0):

For navbar, there is also a div section to push your main content to the right of the navbar menu when it appear (see below) and also a css section to change ths style for smaller screen sizes. You can study the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

 <!--  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Test NavBar</title>

<style>

body {
  background-image: url('background.png');
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}


a {
  color:#a5e5f8;
}


/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  opacity: 0.5;
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  padding-top: 0px; /* Place content 0px from the top */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-width:3px;
}



/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {

  border-top-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  border-width:3px;
  padding: 16px 8px 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#26acff;  /*#a5e5f8*/
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}



/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #000080; /*dark blue*/
}



/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}



/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

</style>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./jsgrid/jsgrid.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./jsgrid/jsgrid-theme.css" />



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<script>

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "230px";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0px";
}

</script>

</head>



<body onload="openNav()">



<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">

  <a href="#" style="margin:0 0 0 40px; border-top-style: none;border-bottom-style: none;"><img src=".\images\apps_menu_icon.png" height="40" width="40"></a>

  <a href="menu1.html"><img src=".\images\file_clipboard_menu_icon.png" height="40" width="40">&nbsp;Menu 1<br/></a>
  <br/><br/>
  <a href="menu2.html"><img src=".\images\graph_menu_icon.png" height="40" width="40">&nbsp;Menu 2<br/></a>
  <br/><br/>
  

<!-- Add all page content inside this div if you want the side nav to push page content to the right (not used if you only want the sidenav to sit on top of the page -->
<div id="main">
  
</div>




<script>

function exit_app() {

    if (confirm("Exit this app？")) {
        window.location.href = "index.html";    
    }
    
}

</script>



</body>

</html>
```